# iOS uilabel over uitextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uilabel

I want to have a label over a textfield, which changes while the user types.
The problem is that the textfield's caret is behind the label (if I put the label in front of the text field). I can always make the textfield's background transparent and add another disabled textfield behind both the label and the textfield, but I would like a better solution.

Comment: Actually what is your requirement and can you explain why you want a label over a textfield ?

Comment: I have a credit card field and a label over it containing XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX which fills the text field. After the user types a digit, it becomes 0XXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX and so on.

Comment: So if you make a text field and behind it a label with X-s.. Why would you need another text field behind both elements? And why do you even need a caret for this? I'd say only display the label and a keyboard for this matter..

Comment: Because I want the textfield look.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the Lable behind the textfield and make the textfield background transparent and Boarderless. and remove the placeholder.
you can use below method to achieve this.

```
- (BOOL) textField: (UITextField *)theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: (NSRange)range replacementString: (NSString *)string
 {

}
```

Comment: As I said, I thought of that option.

Comment: why not you using placeHolder instead of Label ? then put the label elsewhere in the screen and make its alpha=0.0; then just show the text in textfield like :textfield.text=label.text (in the above method you can return the expected string.  )